# Glob matching (wildcards) in fish shell not matching bash behavior

Tags: bash, glob, fish

When I the following command in bash, I get a list of files that match the regular expression I want:

```
$> ls *-[0-9].jtl
benchmark-1422478133-1.jtl  benchmark-1422502883-4.jtl  benchmark-1422915207-2.jtl
```

However, when I run the same command in the fish shell, I get different result:

```
$> ls *-[0-9].jtl
fish: No matches for wildcard '*-[0-9].jtl'.
ls *-[0-9].jtl
   ^
```

How come?

Comment: no idea about the answer, but in bash, that's not regex, that's wildcard. it looks similar, but makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 9):

Fish's documentation does not claim to support the full power of POSIX glob patterns.

Quoting the docs:

> ### Wildcards
>
> If a star (*) or a question mark (?) is present in the parameter, fish attempts to match the given parameter to any files in such a way that:
>
> - `?` can match any single character except `/`.
> - `*` can match any string of characters not containing `/`. This includes matching an empty string.
> - `**` matches any string of characters. This includes matching an empty string. The string may include the `/` character but does not need to.

Notably, there's no mention of character classes, as fish doesn't support them.

If you want globs guaranteed to support all POSIX (fnmatch) features, use a POSIX-compliant or POSIX-superset shell.

Comment: also a small note, with regards to remote wildcards. Bash will allow 'scp remote-host:* mydir' but fish will try to expand it and fail. solution is to quote the remote path.

Comment: So, perhaps, `ls | grep '.*-[0-9]\.jlt'` is the recommended way on the fish shell?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use more extended tool unix `find`. It is very powerful.

- https://kb.iu.edu/d/admm
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unix+find

example: use regular expressions

```
find . -path '.*-[0-9].jtl' -not -path '.*-32.jtl'
```

Answer (score 6):

Fish just needs quotes `"*.conf"` to do the same as bash `*.conf`.

Comment: Why? typing the quotes is a pain!

Comment: yes this is it, too bad we can't have it without quotes

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post, but I think it's worth revisiting this. At time of writing (Mar 2021), the documentation *does* explicitly state supporting wildcards.

> Fish supports the familiar wildcard *. To list all JPEG files:
>
> ```
> > ls *.jpg
> lena.jpg
> meena.jpg
> santa maria.jpg
> ```
>
> You can include multiple wildcards:
>
> ```
> > ls l*.p*
> lena.png
> lesson.pdf
> ```
>
> Especially powerful is the recursive wildcard ** which searches directories recursively:
>
> ```
> > ls /var/**.log
> /var/log/system.log
> /var/run/sntp.log
> ```

However, I still all too frequently run into this same issue

```
[/home/glass ]
><glass@rockpiX-Ubuntu> rm *.log.old
fish: No matches for wildcard “*.log.old”. See `help expand`.
rm *.log.old
   ^
```

Comment: it appears it requires quotes to work as intented

Comment: ooh, good find, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In fish 3+ you could `string match`:

```
ls | string match -r --entire '-[0-9].jtl'
```

options:

- `-r`: regular expression
- `--entire`: returns the entire matching string